# writing multiple text files into arrays python

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, numpy, dir

I'm trying to perform some mathematical functions on the values in the arrays. But I want to do it for more than one file, since it's tedious to use loadtxt for each file. Since each .txt file contains three columns, I want to assign t, x, y as the arrays of those columns. I'm inexperienced in this. I used os.chdir since I'm changing the directory to the files in a specific folder, the problem is defining the arrays.

```
os.chdir(r"F:\Thermal Motion")
files = dir('*.txt')
for i in range(len(files)):
    t, x, y = loadtxt(files(i))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`unpack=True` parameter](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html), to unpack the result into separate `t`, `x`, `y` arrays:

```
from glob import glob
import numpy as np

for path in glob(r"F:\Thermal Motion\*.txt"):
    t, x, y = np.loadtxt(path, unpack=True)
    use_the_arrays_here(x, y, t) # <--  use mathematical functions here
```

Comment: what does the use_the_arrays_here(x,y,t) do, since I get error that this is not defined

Comment: @Kimi, that's just an example, to show where you would do other things with `x`, `y`, and `t`.  It's where you would "perform some mathematical functions on the values in the arrays."

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using the [csvreader](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) library to do a lot of the work for you, if that is allowed by your problem.

Also there's not really a need to use `chdir` if you know the path to the file, just pass the path directly to the open call, or combine the directory and the filename with the following:

```
full_path = os.path.join(dir_path, filename)
```